# TimeoutException using XMemcached 1.3.3

Tags: jakarta-ee, memcached

I am getting TimeoutException when the application is trying to perform an operation (get, set, remove) due to network fluctuation.
Even after the network starts working, the TimeoutException continues.

I caught the TimeoutException and if it is thrown for more than a configured threshold, shut down the client and establishing the connection again. This worked when the load is less but when the load is high, the TimeoutException continues.

I am using XMemcached client 1.3.3

Any ideas on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use memcached binary protocol?

xmemcached 1.3.3 has an issue about binary protocol decoding,and it may cause connection to be closed in an unpredicted way.

You may try to use text protocol or upgrade to xmemcached 1.3.4

Comment: Sorry for getting back late. I was using binary protocol. As per your recommendation, I switched back to text and didn't see this problem.

Comment: I also tried with Xmemcached 1.3.4 using binary protocol but still faced the same timeout issue. Another observation is that under same load (5 tps), the timeout doesn't happen when i run my client and server in Ubuntu whereas it happens in Hp/Unix, Solaris and Windows 7.